# PyQt5 managing a cluster of buttons without having to write cases for each individual one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a layout where the user can click a combination of buttons, each button's click will add a 1 or a 0 to a certain position in a list which is the actual input I'd like to get out of it.
However, I don't know how to manage a cluster of buttons, there are 48 buttons and managing them all individually is the antithesis of DRY.

Here's an example attempt:

```
num_buttons = 48
press_list = [None]*len(num_buttons)
button_list = list()
for button in range(num_buttons):
    some_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(SomeDialog)
    some_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 141, 28))
    some_btn.setObjectName("button_%s" % (button,))
    some_btn.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed(button))


def button_pressed(self, button_num):
    if press_list[button_num] == 1:
        press_list[button_num] = 0
    else:
        press_list[button_num] = 1
```

[image: Heres my QtDesigner layout]

(clicks turn buttons blue), is it possible to have a set geometry through the Qt designer and still do something like this, or will I have to calculate the setGeometry positions and add the buttons through the code?

Comment: Do you want the buttons to be grouped in groups of 12 as shown in the image? Are the labels above the buttons relevant?

Comment: @eyllanesc Not necessarily grouped as 12 but that would be the ideal, the labels are relevant but can be modified, what do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to understand you better, what you want is to have 48 buttons that have a certain distribution (which is not interesting now), and you want that every time you press the state is mapped in a list, if it is checked it is a 1, if it is unchecked a 0 I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc That's exactly right, basically it's a schedule with either two roles, A or B, the user inputs which hours they're working A, and which they are working B. So there are 2 lists of 24 buttons. Could potentially be 1 with 48 buttons, but the logic gets a bit messier with that setup.

Comment: You already confused me more, do not sign 2 options, just point one, I do not know what your final goal is and I do not want to know, I just want to know what you need when asking this question. In short, do you want 2 groups of 24 or 1 group of 48? If it is the first one you want 2 lists that map the state or only 1, and the same for the second case.

Comment: Sorry, 2 lists each one corresponding to a cluster of 24 buttons which when pressed switches a 0 to a 1 in the list in a predefined position depending on what button is pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an additional argument to the slots you can use partial as shown below:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

QSS = """
QToolButton::checked{
    background-color: blue      
}
"""

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listA = [0 for _ in range(24)]
        self.listB = [0 for _ in range(24)]

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        hlay1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay.addLayout(hlay1)
        lay.addLayout(hlay2)

        for i, val in enumerate(self.listA):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
            button.setCheckable(True)
            hlay1.addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.callbackA, i))
            button.setStyleSheet(QSS)

        for i, val in enumerate(self.listB):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
            button.setCheckable(True)
            hlay2.addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.callbackB, i))
            button.setStyleSheet(QSS)


    def callbackA(self, index, state):
        self.listA[index] = 1 if state else 0
        print("listA: ")
        print(self.listA)

    def callbackB(self, index, state):
        self.listB[index] = 1 if state else 0
        print("listB: ")
        print(self.listB)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution, I'm going to get creative with the labels outside of the widget, thank's a lot!